# Provide anonymous access to multiple dynamically uploaded images in location of web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis

How can I specify multiple images in one location 'uploaded' folder elements in web.config? I want to provide anonymous access to all users to one of the application page with uploaded images, images have some random unique name which get decided at run time only. On top that I am using windows authentication for my application or rest of the pages.  I cannot specify each every image file name in web.config. Please suggest.

```
<location path="Dashboard.aspx">
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

```
<location path="uploaded">
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: "I cannot specify each every image file name in web.config." But you have to, as location tag requires an exact name. Revise your web app and put such images in a dedicate folder, then you can set a folder level location tag.

Comment: thanks @Lex, yes I already have dedicated folder named "uploaded" folder which added in web.config for images, still setting folder this solution is not working..